# html and script tag not linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new in angularjs and going through `Egghead.io` videos..but i could not link js page into html page.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <h4>{{ "data.message"}}</h4>
    <div class="{{data.message}}">  
      Wrap me up in component       
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

and my **main.js** file is

```
function FirstCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {message: "panel"};
}
```

Comment: You need to define your app using angular.module(.....)

Comment: And `ng-app=""` needs name

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, that can actually remain the same. It isn't necessary to write the app name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to define your `app` as `var VARIABLE_NAME=angular.module('APP_NAME')` and your controller as `VARIABLE_NAME.controller('CONTROLLER_NAME', FUNCTION_EXPRESSION)`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl);

function FirstCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    message: "panel"
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <h4>{{data.message}}</h4>
    <div class="{{data.message}}">
      Wrap me up in component
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** You should not have quotes(`""`) in your `expressions` or else, it will be treated at string.

Comment: still i cannot link js and html files. I used script inside,outside , top, bottom of the body but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Move these links inside tag

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

and you cannot use $scope with module and controller this must be

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.data = {"message": panel};
        });
```

and in html

```
        <div ng-app="myApp">
```

to first div
and use

```
          {{data.message}}
```